# mysqli auto incremented primary id that was generated

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

```
$insert = "INSERT INTO event_tracker_table (event_name, event_location, location_number, event_creator_username, event_creator_email)

            VALUES (
                    '".$_POST['event_name']."',
                    '".$_POST['event_location']."',
                    '".$_POST['location_number']."',
                    '".phpCAS::getAttribute('uid')."',
                    '".phpCAS::getAttribute('mail')."'
                    )";


            $mysqli->query($insert);
```

How do I get this AUTO INCREMENT that was generated by MySQL? I've tried this but it doesn't work:

```
$statement = $mysqli->query($insert);

echo $statement->insert_id;
```

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.lastinsertid.php

Comment: @Pekka the name of the auto increment primary id is "eventid"

Comment: @E_p I'm not using pdo, I'm using mysqli... Please read the question

Comment: Ahh, I misunderstood. E_p's hint is almost correct - look for the "last insert ID" command in mysqli

Comment: You  want `$mysqli->insert_id`

Comment: @Arian You should start using PDO instead of Mysqli.

Comment: @Pekka I have, the second part of my question... I am trying to use the command but it doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: No, you are using `$statement_insert_id`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Insert id is a property of the MYSQLI object and not the MYSQLI result object:

```
$statement = $mysqli->query($insert);
echo $mysqli->insert_id; // correct
echo $statement->insert_id; //not correct
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php

Comment: Thank you! This answer is very clear and concise, and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the auto_increment value with

```
$id = mysqli_insert_id($mysqli);
```

See [mysqli_insert_id](http://php.net/manual/de/mysqli.insert-id.php) for more info.